# Setting a value of an item in ng-repeat (firebase, angular)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire

So, I have some messages in the Firebase, with `text`, `auther` and `like`. I'm going over them with ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages">
```

and I wanted to add a button for diss/like the message. I tried all kind of stuff, none worked. I hope to find something that works like that:

```
<span ng-if="message.like"><button ng-click="message.$setValue({like: !message.like})">Disslike Message</button></span>
<span ng-if="!message.like"><button ng-click="message.$setValue({like: !message.like})">Like Message</button></span>
```

I also tried to pass the message to a function but also - didn't worked :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I did some mix&match with Sumit & Ven's answers.
Thank you both!

In the html:

```
<button ng-click="message.like = !message.like; invertLike($index)">
    <span ng-show="!message.like">Like Button</span>
    <span ng-show="message.like">Dislike Button</span>
</button>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.invertLike = function(index) {
    $scope.messages.$save(index);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to go about this is to call a controller function, using the `$index` magic variable (which represents the current item's index) – instead of storing functions on the object to modify itself:

```
<button ng-click="invertLike($index)">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.invertLike = function (index) {
  messages[index].like = !messages[index].like;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the text on the button does not update and also the data in the db stays the same.

Comment: You're gonna need some firebase call to update the DB.

Answer (score 2):

I think u want to toggle between like and dislike button at runtime. See below to do that. JSFiddle for reference - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/romtpup8/)
Hope this helps!

```
<body ng-app="SampleApp">
  <table ng-controller="myController" border="1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>author</td>
        <td>like/dislike button</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="message  in messages">
      <tr>
        <td>{{message.text}}</td>
        <td>{{message.author}}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="message.like = !message.like">
            <span ng-show="message.like">Like Button</span>
            <span ng-show="!message.like">Dislike Button</span>
          </button>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks!
The text on the button does change as I wanted, but the data in the db does not update...